# Basic SQL union all as tmp

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

New to SQL and had a general question regarding a pretty basic union all statement. I'm looking at a piece of code that looks like this:

```
select * 
into ConsolidatedTable 
from 
    (select * from Table1
     union all
     select * from Table2
     union all
     select * from Table3) as tmp;
```

Is it necessary to have 'as tmp'?  If so, why?

Thanks!

Comment: that is an alias. You can give any name of your choice.. It can be Dave also.. But you should give alias for sure

Comment: Thanks Shakeer, but is it necessary?  What happens if 'as tmp' wasn't there?

Comment: will throw an error `Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: An alias removes ambiguity when you have more than one table because you know which table it comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server, yes, an alias is *required* for the inline view.  If the alias is omitted, SQL Server will throw an error.

The `AS` keyword before the alias is optional, and is not required.

(My personal preference is to omit the `AS` keyword for table/view aliases, and to always include the `AS` keyword for column aliases.)

---

The `AS` keyword for a table/view alias is optional in SQL Server. (It's not part of the ANSI SQL standard.) Some databases (such as Oracle) do not accept the `AS` keyword before a table or view alias, and will throw an error if it's included.

Some databases, such as MySQL and SQL Server *require* that an alias be assigned to an inline view.  Databases that do *not* require an alias on an inline view (e.g. Oracle) allow for an alias, and having an alias assigned allows us qualify column references in the outer query.  Since qualifying column references is our normal pattern, assigning an alias to an inline view is also our normal pattern, even for databases that don't require it.

Note that the assignment of an alias is *unrelated* to the usage of `UNION ALL` in the inline view query.

Comment: got it, so the last line of code could be simply: select * from Table3) tmp?

Comment: @Dave yes, exactly. That pattern can consistently be followed in SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, et al.

Answer (score 1):

tmp is called an alias. It is mandatory because otherwise the columns in the inline view (all code encased in parantheses) would become "unreachable" in the rest of the query, as in you would not be able to reference them.

It could have any name you wish, it's only used for further reference.

And, to answer your last question, is it necessary to have 'as tmp'? - since this is sql server, you can directly write the alias name without the 'as' - so `) tmp` would suffice.